# Confusion with System.ApplicationId;

Tags: c#

Reading and messing around to understand static classes and static methods and their differences with non static methods and their usage which i still don't get except maybe for the Main method which must not be made an instance(object) of a class.

Why if i try to use:

```
using static System.ApplicationId;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Copy(SOMETHING)// Copy method doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Then try to use a method from **ApplicationId** like `Copy();`

The IDE? can't find the method?

Doing the same with:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Writeline("Hello"); // OK
    }
}
```

Then try to find a method from **Console** like `WriteLine();`

It can find it and i can use it.

Why does that happen?

My understanding is That those are both static members? Isn't that the reason why i cant make instances of those 2 classes? Yet i can use the methods in the second example but not in the first one since it seems that it doesn't let me (error: copy() doesn't exist in the current context...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you wouldn't use the `static` keyword in a `using` statement for non-static namespaces like `System.ApplicationId`
To use methods on a non-static (instance) class, you have to first make an instance of it using `new`. 
The tl;dr part follows
To avoid having to write out the namespace prefix `System.` every time you want to refer to `ApplicationId`, you can add

```
using System;
```

and then in the class, you can get to the someMethod() method with:

```
new ApplicationId().someMethod();
```

**Now let's talk about static:**

Before C# version 6, you just couldn't use a `using` statement on a static class, so to get access to a static method like

```
System.Console.WriteLine()
```

you'd first add the non-static parent (`System`) with

```
using System
```

and then refer to the static method using the namespace

```
Console.WriteLine
```

With the `using static` syntax, you add the '`Console.`' part of the namespace once per class on the `using` statement like so:

```
`using static System.Console;`
```

and then you can use `WriteLine()` instead of `Console.WriteLine`. I have to guess that the `WriteLine()` method has got to be the most common use case for this functionality.

If you check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx it shows that System.Console is a static class, so `using static` is appropriate there.
However, System.ApplicationId is non-static (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so you can't use `using static`.

Comment: Thanks I get it :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple, the methods in `ApplicationId` are *not* marked as `static`.

Let's see the difference between static and instance methods:

Static method:

```
Console.WriteLine();
******* *********
 ^         ^
class    method
name     name
```

Instance methods:

```
Random aRandomObject = new Random();
aRandomObject.Next();
************* ****
      ^        ^
name of an    method
instance of   name
Random
```

As you can see here, you need an instance of that class in order to use non-static methods. But for static methods, you don't need an instance.

The `using static` directive allows you to omit the class name when you call a *static* method.

"But why doesn't it allow us to call instance methods like this?" you asked. As I have said above, you need an instance to call instance methods. If you only write the method name to call the method, how can the compiler know what instance do you want to call it on?

Answer (score 0):

ApplocationId is not a static class, so you need to create an instance of it.